# Reading json input on Jersey which can be both nullable and optional

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I currently have the following REST end-point

```
@PUT
@Path("/props")
public Response update(Props input) { .. }
```

and my input parameter is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Props {
    public String prop1;
    public String prop2;
}
```

Client sends input as json string. I want both parameter to be nullable and optional. Example: if a client wants to update prop2 to a null value without updating prop1 it may send:

```
{"prop2":null}
```

But at this point I see both `input.prop1 = null` and `input.prop2 = null`.

How can I distinguish if client has sent a prop with null value or has not sent it at all?

Comment: Since Java String only has `null` and not-`null`, how do you want your code to distinguish the cases "sent as null" from "not sent"?

Comment: @dbreaux This is what i'm asking. I expect that such common problem has some kind of legacy solution

Comment: Since Java has no natural way to distinguish sent-as-null from not-sent, I doubt there's a standard JAXB/JSON unmarshall behavior for that. I suspect any of the major libraries will unmarshall both cases as null. The only alternative in Java would be some special string defined to mean "omitted". You might have to parse it yourself with lower-level API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Isn’t it better to just make it an empty string if you want to set it as null, and null if did not really sent something at all?

Comment: This does not make you distinguish if a value is not passed or is passed with $custom-null value

Comment: you could also pass another parameter which is a combination of all passed params

Answer (score 0):

All reference type variables are being initialized with null. You may choose some `meaningless' value for initialization.

Comment: Thanks for idea. I'm currently looking for something more.. sound. But this will be my backup solution

Comment: hmmm. Another approach would be to accept Map<String, Obbject> as `update' method parameter and check it with Map.containsKey()